# How to target children of child pages

Tags: menus, child-pages

I would like to apply special styling to the menu items of pages that are children of child pages. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `CSS` rule to your stylesheet:

```
ul.menu ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu li{
   //special styling here
}
```

its the default `CSS` classnaming `WordPress` use for the menus, you can see how i add it here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking only for styling you can go something like this:

```
ul ( main-items ) > ul ( secondary menu ) > ul ( third level menu ).
```

You can provide more information about what exactly you need to style and the context.

Answer (score 1):

You can target your elements with jQuery using these methods:

**children()**:https://api.jquery.com/children/

*or*

**find()**: https://api.jquery.com/find/

You may have some class you could target like .dropdown-menu or something else.